# Set keybindings in a certain perspective in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have overridden the search keybinding for eclipse RCP and now it's working for ALL the perspectives (the perspective I have already created, the debug ,... etc) I want to have my OWN search to work ONLY for my perspective and to have the ECLIPSE DEFAULT SEARCH for all the other perspectives.
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: In Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys. do you see a **when** select box?

Comment: I want to change it programmatically and not by this,,, in addition I didn't find my perspective in the When select box

Comment: Can you help me know how to make it in the plugin_configuration.ini?